# Line Chart Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am trying a line Chart i.e http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic . There is a need to display the series name after the last point of each series. Tried with different plot options with line and series. However could not do it.

Can somebody help?

```
function GChart() {
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var Options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            defaultSeriesType: 'line',
            marginRight: 100,
            marginBottom: 40
        },
        title: {
            x: -20
        },
        subtitle: {
        },
        xAxis: {
        categories: []
        },
        yAxis: {
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                this.x + ': ' + this.y +      'Kg.';
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        },
        series: []
    };

    $.get('Newchart.html', function(data) {
        var fulldata = document.getElementById("MyHiddenField").value;
        var MyChartTitle = document.getElementById("MyChartTitle").value;
        var MyChartSubTitle = document.getElementById("MyChartSubTitle").value;
        var MyChartXTitle = document.getElementById("MyChartXTitle").value;
        var MyChartYTitle = document.getElementById("MyChartYTitle").value;

        var lines = fulldata.split('$');
        var series = [];
        var temp;

        $.each(lines, function(lineno, line) {
            temp = line.split('#');
            series.data = JSON.parse("[" + temp[1] + "]");
            series.name = temp[0];
            if (lineno == 0) {
                series.color = "#FF0000";
            }
            else {
                series.color = "#058DC7";
            }

            series.push({ name: series.name, data: series.data, color: series.color });
        });
        Options.series = series;
        Options.title = { text: MyChartTitle, align: 'left', x: 90, y: 74, floating: true };
        Options.subtitle = { text: MyChartSubTitle, align: 'left', x: 120, y: 87, floating: true };
        Options.xAxis.title = { text: MyChartXTitle };
        Options.yAxis.title = { text: MyChartYTitle };
        Options.yAxis.tickInterval = 5;
        Options.xAxis.tickInterval = 1;
        Options.xAxis.min = 5;
        Options.yAxis.min = 5;
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(Options);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: What's your problem? Don't you have a series name? Do you have two of them? Don't you know how to do it?

Comment: I have  series names for five series, however when chart renders..I want to display series name at the very last point of each series. And I am not getting it , how to do it..

Answer (score 3):

I would use the [Highcharts.Renderer](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#renderer) for this and add the series name at the end of each line.  This for example after the chart call:

```
$(chart.series).each(function()
{
  var point = this.points[this.points.length-1];
  chart.renderer.text(this.name,
  point.plotX + chart.plotLeft + 5,
  point.plotY + chart.plotTop + 5).attr(
    {
      zIndex: 5
    }).add();
});
```

Produces this (fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TkRXA/)):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of a label on the end of a line using the dataLabel property under plotOptions. The data label can be attached on a per point basis, in this case just show it for the last point.  Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/gK52f/1/

The way to enable the data label on just one point is to pass additional properties for that point in the data array (under series).  I passed this in for the last point and used the formatter to return the series name.  This overrides the default formatter which returns y value.

```
       {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                align: 'left',
                crop: false,
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.series.name;
                },
                x: 5,
                verticalAlign: 'middle'
            },
            y: 54.4
       }
```